# How do you count the sum of all values in an array up until a point?

Tags: python, arrays, sum

Okay, so I was doing some practice problems for USACO and noticed that for one of the problems, you needed to add all values of an array up to a certain value. For an example, say that a = [0, 5, 7, 3, 9]. You need to find the value of all the sum of the numbers up to a certain value, but you don't know what the value is( Like the value could be a[2], a[3], a[4] or anything) Also, the array is different every time. How would you find the sum of all values up to a certain place in the array?

Comment: Practice problems or actual problems? Regardless, this should be easy to find with some googling (try searching for prefix sums).

Comment: What do you want to happen when asked to sum a `list` up to a value which doesn't actually exist there?

Comment: Just for better clarity, could you fill in your example? You've got your list `a`, but what value should you sum up to, and what should be the output?

Comment: You don't know what the value is, or you don't know the _index_ of the value? If you need to sum to a value but you don't know what that value is... that's impossible.

Comment: Aplet123, It was for the practice problem buckets. Why do you ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find the index of the value and the sum the sublist up untill it :

```
arr = [0, 5, 7, 3, 9]

up_to = 3
sum(arr[:arr.index(up_to)])
>>>12
```

if you want to include the value:

```
sum(arr[:arr.index(up_to) + 1])
>>>15
```